# Data structure to use, for large data sets from file

Tags: database, data-structures, storage, disk

Good day,

I am doing a research thats involved in handling a large data set from a given file (file1). From my understanding, a data storage is on a different level from data structure but overlaps, for example, data structure is the arrangement of data in memory, as well as disk storages.

I need to use another file (file2, which is given) and then compare each value with the value in the first given file (file1), to see if it's there or not.

When comparing between files, I would dump the results in another file (file3). This file will be structured into different columns (since I mentioned columns, perhaps use database for the results instead of file3?)

Based on what I said above, it looks like I am just looking for quick search/lookup (to compare between files).

My question is, do you think this is better suited for data structure, or should I search the file as is? I mentioned that I am just looking for search/lookup operation, I am leaning towards hash table, which has constant time O(1) when it comes to search. On the other time, I feel like data structure is an overkill to handle data that is already constructed using different storage mechanism (file), and data structure is best left for when entering the data as we go..

Hope this makes sense. Am I in the right track of thinking?

Comment: G'day :) If this is one-time task and data files are not too large, then I would just use Excel :) If this is recurring task or data doesn't fit into excel, then maybe some flavour of SQL server comes handy? This way you only have to implement data import and wrote simple query - no need to think about data storage, structures, O(something) search algorithms etc. Of course this is just pragmatic approach :)

Comment: Thanks. Will data structure be used if data is not available but set over time?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand. (I'm not english speaker.)

Answer (score 1):

For a small file, you can read everything into a hashtable, indexed by the key.

For a large file, you could scan the file, and store the key and file offset into a hashtable.

Pseduo-C#:

```cs
var lookup = new Dictionary<string, long>(); // Hashtable

foreach (Record record1 in EnumerateRecords(file1))
{
    lookup[record1.Key] = file1.Position - sizeof(Record);
}

foreach (Record record2 in EnumerateRecords(file2))
{
    long file1Position;
    if (lookup.TryGetValue(record2.Key, out file1Position))
    {
        // Record exists in both files
        file1.Seek(file1Position);
        Record record1 = ReadRecord(file1);
        Process(record1, record2);

        // Remove what we found, so we know what is in file1
        // but not in file2
        lookup.Remove(record2.Key);
    }
    else
    {
        // Record exists only in file2
        Process(null, record2);
    }
}

foreach (var keyValuePair in lookup)
{
    // Record exists only in file1
    var file1Position = keyValuePair.Value;
    file1.Seek(file1Position ;
    var record1 = ReadRecord(file1);
    Process(record1, null);
}
```

If you need to, you could scan both files, and store the offsets. Then compare the two hashtables for matches.